# Multiple OneDrive accounts on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, configuration, microsoft

I am a total newb here. I have two OneDrive accoutns, one for work and the other for personal use. How can I set up OneDrive in Ubuntu 18.04 to sync both accounts?

Answer (score 2):

> I use OneDrive Free Client.

The 'skilion' client was abandoned in 2018. It contains many defects that put you at risk of data loss and corruption if you use it. All new development since April 2018 is beign done here: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

Follow the directions here: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.md to install the correct client version.

To then configure multi-accounts, please refer to https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/USAGE.md#using-multiple-onedrive-accounts and https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/wiki/OneDrive-Client-Multi-Account-Configuration-Assistance

Answer (score 1):

I use **[OneDrive Free Client](https://github.com/skilion/onedrive)**.
When setting it up, be sure to **complete the Configuration and OneDrive service steps**.

We can now set up multiple accounts.
Start by making a new local onedrive and .config

```
mkdir ~/OneDriveWork && mkdir ~/.config/onedriveWork && cp ~/.config/onedrive/config ~/.config/onedriveWork/
```

edit sync_dir in the config file to *sync_dir = "~/OneDriveWork"*

```
nano .config/onedriveWork/config
```

Copy the service you have created in the initial setup

```
cp /usr/lib/systemd/user/onedrive.service /usr/lib/systemd/user/onedriveWork.service
```

Edit the new service configuration directory

```
sudo nano /usr/lib/systemd/user/onedriveWork.service
```

add *--confdir="~/.config/onedriveWork"* to the end of *ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/onedrive -m*

add onedriveWork service to autostart

```
systemctl --user enable onedriveWork && systemctl --user start onedriveWork
```

run onedrive and repeat the first time run instructions, similar to the initial setup, this time with your work account login.

`onedrive --monitor --confdir="~/.config/onedriveWork`

Reboot

Hope this helps!