# Syncing Onedrive personal and work accounts Simultaneously

Tags: 18.04, sync

I have a personal and work account in Onedrive. I have successfully run my personal account using the Onedrive free client but couldn't run multiple accounts. I tried several methods but to no success. Even tried this one "[Multiple OneDrive accounts on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112231/multiple-onedrive-accounts-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/1193932#1193932)". Still no success. When I execute the command "onedrive --monitor --confdir="~/.config/onedriveWork" the cursor changes from $ to > but then nothing happens, just blank command line with cursor blinking. Can anyone shed light on this in plain simple words or step please as I am no expert. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I have a personal and work account in Onedrive. I have successfully run my personal account using the Onedrive free client but couldn't run multiple accounts.

Your first issue is you are running Ubuntu 18.x, which, depending on how you installed the client, you potentially will have a very outdated client version.

Follow the directions here: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.md to install the correct client version.

To then configure multi-accounts, please refer to https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/USAGE.md#using-multiple-onedrive-accounts and https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/wiki/OneDrive-Client-Multi-Account-Configuration-Assistance

Comment: I tried to follow but since I am not expert, the process didn't work. It's complicated. Can you please guide using step by step? Thanks